# Shorten Sentence using Python Library like nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am using `Nltk` to remove stopwords from a sentence.

eg. `"I would love to fly again via American Airlines"`

Result: `"Love to fly American Airlines"`

I had tried the following Code :

```
# Tokenizing the text 
txt = "I love to fly with American Airlines"
stopWords = set(stopwords.words("english")) 
words = word_tokenize(txt) 

# Creating a frequency table to keep the  
# score of each word 

freqTable = dict() 
for word in words: 
    word = word.lower() 
    if word in stopWords: 
        continue
    if word in freqTable: 
        freqTable[word] += 1
    else: 
        freqTable[word] = 1

# Creating a dictionary to keep the score 
# of each sentence 
sentences = sent_tokenize(txt) 
sentenceValue = dict() 

for sentence in sentences: 
    for word, freq in freqTable.items(): 
        if word in sentence.lower(): 
            if sentence in sentenceValue: 
                sentenceValue[sentence] += freq 
            else: 
                sentenceValue[sentence] = freq 



sumValues = 0
for sentence in sentenceValue: 
    sumValues += sentenceValue[sentence] 

# Average value of a sentence from the original text 

average = int(sumValues / len(sentenceValue)) 

# Storing sentences into our summary. 
summary = '' 
for sentence in sentences: 
    if (sentence in sentenceValue) and (sentenceValue[sentence] > (1.2 * average)): 
        summary += " " + sentence 

print("Summary: " + summary)
```

This result is an empty string because I think the sentence is too short for `Nltk` to work. Just researching if there's an easier approach to this, I'm planning to train a model for this.

Comment: post the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python Library that can easily and efficiently shorten the Sentence by removing stop words is `nlkt`, you are using it too. but there might be some problem with your approch(Logic or code).

The below code works perfectly

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
 
example_sent = "I love to fly with American Airlines"
  
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
  
word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_sent) 
  
filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
  
filtered_sentence = [] 
  
for w in word_tokens: 
    if w not in stop_words: 
        filtered_sentence.append(w) 
  
print(word_tokens)
print(filtered_sentence)
print(" ".join(filtered_sentence))
```

Comment: this simple code is exactly what im looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You're generating `filtered_sentence` twice. Are you doing this to show two ways of doing it?

Comment: @JosephChotard yes, first one is using List comprehension and another one is using Traditional for loop